# Find the mclaurin series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Find the mcLaurin series of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ and

$g(x)=ln|1-x| $ and find the radius of convergence.

Soll.

i find the derivatives of $f(x)$ at 0. noticing that $f(0)=1$ ,$f'(0)=1$,$f''(0)=2$
$f'''(0)=6$ .

So taking the formula i get the mclaurin series of $f=\sum x^n $.
How do i find the radius . And what about the logarithm . I can see the derivative of the logarithm seems like $f$.

Comment: $f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ is a GP series. It converges only if $|x|<1$

Comment: What about the logarithm ? Compute the derivatives at $0$ just like you did for $1/(1-x)$. You'll learn something.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to the the series for $f(x)$ is to use the formula for summing a geometric series.  $1+r+r^2+\cdots = \frac{1}{1-r}$ and just plug in $x$ for $r$.  You can get the radius of convergence by using ratio test:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left| \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n} \right| = |x|<1.$$

There is a theorem that say if the radius of convergence of $f(x)$ is $R$, then that's also the radius of convergence of $f'(x)$ and of $\int f.$

Comment: how you got |x|<1

Comment: The "1" comes from the _ratio test_.   You studied it a few sections back.

Comment: why im using the ratio test for convergence to find the radius?  the ratio test tells me if the series converge. not where they do. Link me where to read about it.Or you can tell me.

Comment: Or you could look in your text.  I'll bet a zillion dollars that every example in your text about radius of convergence involves the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

Near $0$,  $1-x>0$ thus
$$g (x)=\ln (1-x) $$
and
$$g'(x)=-f (x) $$

$$g (x)=g (0 )+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac {g^{(k)} (0)}{k!}x^k $$

but
$$g^{(k)}(0 )=-f^{(k-1)}(0)=-(k-1)!$$
thus

$$g (x)=-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac {x^k}{k} $$
$$=-(x+\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {x^3}{3}+.... $$

by ratio test, the ROC is $1$.

Comment: RoC, maybe, unless you refer to the République du Congo ;-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's Rayon De Convergence.

Comment: Evidemment, mais pas en Anglais.

Comment: @YvesDaoust en anglais, c'est Republic Of Congo.

Comment: Mh, ROC usually stands for Republic of China, i.e. Taiwan.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok c'est bon. merci et à bientôt. Salut.

Answer (score 0):

You also can integrate your first series for $1/(1-x)$, and you'll get
$$\int_0^{x}{\frac{dt}{1-t}} = \int_0^x{(1 + t + t^2 + t^3 + ... )}dt$$
$$-\ln(1 - x) = x + x^2/2 +x^3/3 + x^4/4 + ... $$
$$\ln(1 - x) = -x -x^2/2 -x^3/3 -x^4/4 - ... $$
As it was mentioned in other answers, the series converges only at $|x| < 1$, so the absolute values here is redunant. For the integral series the convergence interval is the same.

Comment: |x|<0 ?? what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, it's an error. Fixed it.